# Expanded listview in column takes up extra space

Tags: listview, flutter

I have two listviews in a column. I want the first listview to take up as little space as possible. So if there is one item in the list, the size of the box containing the listview should be one item tall.
I have tried to use a container for the ListView but then i get an error telling me to use Expanded or Flexible with using FitFit.loose. The problem with using these, is that they both cause the ListView to have extra padding.

[image: The red in this screenshot is the problem]

In this screenshot you can see a bit of red under the first request. That's part of the Expanded containing my ListView.

This is my code:

```
return new Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
  appBar: new PreferredSize(
    child: GradientAppBar(includeLogo: false),
    preferredSize: new Size.fromHeight(75.0),
  ),
  body: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 0.0),
          child: TextField(
            onChanged: (text) {
              setState(() {
                _searchText = text;
              });
              print("search text: $text");
            },
            decoration: new InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Search',
                contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
                border: InputBorder.none,
                hintStyle: new TextStyle(
                    color: Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor),
                icon: new Icon(searchIcon,
                    color: Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor)),
          )),
      FutureBuilder<FriendRequests>(
        future: fetchFriendRequests(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.friendRequests.length > 0) {
            return Flexible(
                child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <
                    Widget>[
              Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Theme.of(context).bottomAppBarColor,
                      border: new Border(
                          bottom: new BorderSide(
                              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                              width: 1.0,
                              style: BorderStyle.solid),
                          top: new BorderSide(
                              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                              width: 1.0,
                              style: BorderStyle.solid))),
                  child: Center(child: Text("Requests"))),
              Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                      child: new ListView.builder(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: snapshot.data.friendRequests.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return new Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: <Widget>[
                              new Container(
                                decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                    color:
                                        Theme.of(context).backgroundColor,
                                    border: new Border.all(
                                        color:
                                            Theme.of(context).accentColor)),
                                child: new FriendRequestView(
                                    snapshot.data.friendRequests[index]
                                        .friendName,
                                    snapshot.data.friendRequests[index]
                                        .pictureURL,
                                    snapshot.data.friendRequests[index].id,
                                    snapshot.data.friendRequests[index]
                                        .creationDate),
                              )
                            ],
                          );
                        },
                      )))
            ]));
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          } else if (snapshot.hasData &&
              snapshot.data.friendRequests.length == 0) {
            return Container();
          }

          // By default, show a loading spinner
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        },
      ),
      Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Theme.of(context).bottomAppBarColor,
              border: new Border(
                  bottom: new BorderSide(
                      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                      width: 1.0,
                      style: BorderStyle.solid),
                  top: new BorderSide(
                      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                      width: 1.0,
                      style: BorderStyle.solid))),
          child: Center(child: Text("Suggestions"))),
      FriendSuggestionsView(
        searchText: _searchText,
      )
    ],
  ),
);
```

This is my FriendSuggestionsView:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Flexible(
    child: FutureBuilder<FriendSuggestions>(
        future: fetchSuggestions(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData &&
              snapshot.data.friendSuggestions.length > 0) {
            return new ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.friendSuggestions.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return FriendSuggestionRow(
                      name: snapshot.data.friendSuggestions[index].name,
                      userID: snapshot.data.friendSuggestions[index].userID,
                      pictureURL: snapshot
                          .data.friendSuggestions[index].pictureURL);
                });
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return Text("${snapshot.error}");
          } else if (snapshot.hasData &&
              snapshot.data.friendSuggestions.length == 0) {
            return Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Center(child: Text("No suggestions")));
          }

          // By default, show a loading spinner
          return Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
              child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
        }));
```

}

Comment: What should happen in case the first list content is bigger than screen remaining height?

Comment: @tomwyr There should be a max height on the first list content.

Comment: https://flutter.io/debugging/#visual-debugging provides some guideance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Under `FutureBuilder`, you should be using `Flexible` containers instead of `Expanded`, to prevent taking excessive space by their children. You also need to set [shrinkWrap](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/ScrollView/shrinkWrap.html) property to `true` when building *requests* `ListView`. Pay attention, however, to the last paragraph of the documentation:

> Shrink wrapping the content of the scroll view is significantly more expensive than expanding to the maximum allowed size (...).

Update:
According to additional informations provided, here's how can you prevent *suggestions* from overlapping *requests*.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    ..., // other scaffold properties
    body: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
      children: [
        ..., // search field widget
        Expanded(
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (context, constraints) => Column(children: [
                  LimitedBox(
                    maxHeight: constraints.maxHeight / 2,
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        ..., // requests header widget
                        FutureBuilder<FriendRequests>(
                          future: fetchFriendRequests(),
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.hasData &&
                                snapshot.data.friendRequests.length > 0) {
                              return Flexible(
                                child: Container(
                                  ..., // box decoration
                                  child: new ListView.builder(
                                    shrinkWrap: true,
                                    ..., // item count and builder
                                  ),
                                ),
                              );
                            } else ... // handle other data states
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        ..., // suggestions header widget
                        FutureBuilder<FriendSuggestions>(
                          future: fetchSuggestions(),
                          builder: (context, snapshot) {
                            if (snapshot.hasData &&
                                snapshot.data.friendSuggestions.length > 0) {
                              return Expanded(
                                child: new ListView.builder(
                                  ..., // item count and builder
                                ),
                              );
                            } else ... // handle other data states
                          },
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion and edited the OP. It works perfectly when there is 0-2 suggestions. However the suggestions expand to fill the entire view, overlapping the requests. Here is a gallery that hopefully explains a bit better: https://imgur.com/a/Sk1ZWXp

Comment: Could you elaborate on how do you want layout to behave in case there are multiple items both in requests and suggestions? I.e. should both list views be visible and scrollable, or rather, all requests should scroll first and suggestions  right after them?

Comment: Both views should be visible and scrollable i.e a max height on requests, but infinite height on suggestions.

Comment: @MikeBellika I updated the answer, please take a look and let me know if that's correct behavior. I also removed several lines of code to keep it possibly short.

Comment: This almost works, however when there is only 1 friend request the suggestions don't take up the rest of the space: https://imgur.com/a/LkBWNHi

Comment: Updated the answer once again, please have a look. In short, *requests* column is now wrapped in `LayoutBuilder` and `LimitedBox` widgets. *Flexible* and *shrinkWrap* make requests list as short as possible, whereas *LimitedBox* prevents it from taking more than half height of the screen.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue, and after doing some research I found out a solution that worked out for me:
**You have to specify EdgeInsets.zero for the padding property.**

Answer (score 5):

Use `padding: EdgeInsets.zero,`In `ListView.builder`

```
ListView.builder(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: 3,
                      physics: ScrollPhysics(),
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return Container(
                       
                        );
                      },
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually removes the extra top padding from the listview:

```
   MediaQuery.removePadding(
           context:context,
            removeTop: true,
             child  ListView.Builder(
              itemCount:2,
              itemBuilder(context,index){
          });
```